# How can I show my manager and my director that different teams require desktops/laptops with different characteristics

Tags: professionalism, management, productivity

I'm wondering what's the best argument to prove to manager and my director that different teams require desktops/laptops with different characteristics?

I work for a medium sized company (+-350 employees) and the people responsible for choosing the hardware we use, insist that everyone must have hardware with the same characteristics...

So we have teams of consultants, QA, designers, programmers over a mainframe and web programmers. And for some reason everyone has a i5 4210, with 8 GB of RAM and a 750 HDD, except the designers that have iMac's, at least there they didn't force them to be like everyone else ( Thankfully :) ).

How can I prove to them that if the web programmer team (Java/JSP running all in local servers) would improve dramatically if they had a SSD and more RAM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pick a large program, do a build on a company machine and the same one on a fast machine with better CPU and SSD (and maybe 16 GB, 8 GB is not *bad*), calculate the time difference. Multiply with the number of programmers and the number of builds per unit of time.
FWIW My colleague sitting next to me works in Visual Studio + Xamarin Android. When he builds to the Android emulator that takes >1 minute on a decent machine - *with every build*.

And maybe this helps:

[Does giving a developer a slower development machine result in faster/more efficient code?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13623/does-giving-a-developer-a-slower-development-machine-result-in-faster-more-effic)

[The Programmer's Bill of Rights](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-programmers-bill-of-rights/)

[Are long compiles a thing of the past?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/257344/are-long-compiles-a-thing-of-the-past)

Here's an answer from the first link that really drives it home:
**I like long compile times. It gives me more time to work on my resume.**

From XKCD:
[image]